# android app for long audio files that saves playback position

Tags: android, audio, audiobook

I am looking for an app that with the following characteristics:

- It saves the current playback position even if the phone is rebooted
- (preferably) it can play files from drive and keep saving playback even if the audio file is not downloaded into the phone memory
- (preferably) it has screen commands to rewind or fast-forward by 5-10 seconds
- can play as many audio formats as possible, .mp3 is a must
- (preferably) free or very low price

So far I tried BeyondPod, which does save the playback position but only works with podcasts; and doubleTwist and Transcribe Player, which do not save playback position when I close the app.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I know that VLC does all of this on a PC, but I also know the iPhone version is different.  Not sure abotu the Android version.

Comment: VLC was the first one I tried and unfortunately it does not, unless I did not use it correctly

Comment: My new question is related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85183/android-app-for-playing-audio-files-at-high-speed